# How to select an individual item from an array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

How can I select a **specific item** from an array of tuples? For example:

```
myArray = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
```

How would I specifically select **1** from this array?

Comment: `myArray[0][0]` Tuples and lists can be indexed to access values in similar fashion.

Comment: Like this `myArray[0][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 was of doing so:

`tuple = myArray[0]
item = tuple[0]`

or for short

`item = myArray[0][0]`

Comment: Thank you this has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The list is indexed starting from zero upto (no.of elements)-1. So myArray[0] represents the first tuple(1,2,3) and myArray [1] represents the second tuple(4,5,6). In case you want to access an element within that tuplw,use further indexing. Inside each tuple are three elements indexed from 0 to 2. So for first tuple myArray[0][0]
gives first element 1 ,myArray[0][1]
gives second element 2 , and myArray[0][2]
gives third element 3.

Comment: Thank you this has helped :)